# How to know how many words a paragraph contains in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function

What MySQL function can I use?

for example,

> What Mysql function can I use?

contains 6 words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built in a function that I know if, but I found this in the comments of MySQL's [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) documentation:

---

I was looking for word_count("string") in mysql, finally came up with an user defined function which is very usefull for me, note: I used  for actual space.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS word_count;
CREATE FUNCTION word_count (f_string text(5000)) RETURNS smallint(10)
BEGIN
DECLARE new_string text(5000);
WHILE INSTR(f_string,'<space><space>')>0
DO
SET new_string=(select REPLACE(f_string,'<space><space>','<space>'));
SET f_string=new_string;
END WHILE;

RETURN (select LENGTH(TRIM(f_string))-LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(f_string),'<space>',''))+1);
END
//
```

Here is the result

> mysql> select word_count("Balaji Devarajan") WORD_COUNT;

```
+------------+
| WORD_COUNT |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> mysql> select word_count(" Balaji Devarajan ") WORD_COUNT;

```
+------------+
| WORD_COUNT |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> mysql> select word_count("Balaji Devarajan") WORD_COUNT;

```
+------------+
| WORD_COUNT |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: FWIW, this only works for me if I change the delimiter. So, to make it work, add the line "DELIMITER $$" before "CREATE FUNCTION..."

Answer (score 1):

There is no function to count words in MySQL (or ANSI SQL, or any other DBMS I'm familiar with).

You could *maybe* fake it by counting the number of spaces in the text using a string replace:

```
SELECT LENGTH(colname)-LENGTH(REPLACE(colname, ' ', ''))+1 AS wordcount FROM tablename;
```

This isn't really a word count but would work as long as every word is separated by exactly one space.

To get better word matching you would need a regex, but there is no regex replace in MySQL so you can't use the replace trick. You could select specifically 6-word long values using a `REGEXP`/`RLIKE` match though:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE colname RLIKE '^[^[:alnum:]]*[[:alnum:]]+([^[:alnum:]]+[[:alnum:]]+){5}[^[:alnum:]]*$';
```

Either way, this is slow. It will have to do a string replace or regex match on every row of the table every time you do the query. If number-of-words is a query you are doing often you will want to optimise (denormalise) the table by adding a (possibly indexed) column to store the number of words.